# How can I integrate multiple objects into a single physics based rigidbody?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have [these](https://youtu.be/evvqp9TGxmk) cubes that I can drag around the scene. What I'm trying to do is have these cubes integrate/snap/attach or whatever you want to call it. When they get close to each other like in the video, I want them to attach to each other and act as one object instead of dragging apart from each other? This is the code I have to drag the cubes:

```
﻿using System.Collections; 

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class dragtest7 : MonoBehaviour
{

public float minY = 0.427f;
public float maxY = 0.427f;

public float minZ = 6.536f;
public float maxZ = 15.528f;

public float minX = -5.5f;
public float maxX = 3.493f;

public float minYR = 0;
public float maxYR = 0;

public float minZR = 0;
public float maxZR = 0;

public float minXR = 0;
public float maxXR = 0;



void OnMouseDrag()
{
    float distance = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position).z;
   GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, distance)));
}

void Update()
{
    Vector3 currentPosition = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position;
    Vector3 currentRotation = GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation.eulerAngles;

    currentPosition.y = Mathf.Clamp(currentPosition.y, minY, maxY);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = currentPosition;

    currentPosition.z = Mathf.Clamp(currentPosition.z, minZ, maxZ);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = currentPosition;

    currentPosition.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentPosition.x, minX, maxX);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position = currentPosition;

    currentRotation.y = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.y, minYR, maxYR);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);

    currentRotation.z = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.z, minZR, maxZR);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);

    currentRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.x, minXR, maxXR);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().rotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use [Fixed joint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FixedJoint.html) for this. The fixed joint will allow you to connect two rigidbodies into a single rigid body. Basically Add Fixedjoint on a gameobject and OnCollisionEnter you just attach connectedBody as the collided object. This should allow you to connect two object as one.

I havent worked anytime with fixedjoint so did a bit digging and made small program to have two cubes to merge and act as single object. It does work as complete object. In your case you will require multple fixedjoints to combine multiple objects. Here is a small script I made to attach two cubes.Hope this helps you in your work.

```
Rigidbody currentRigidBody;
FixedJoint fixedJointObj;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () 
{
    currentRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        currentRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(-1, 0, 0));
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        currentRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(1, 0, 0));
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        currentRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, 1, 0));
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        currentRigidBody.AddForce(new Vector3(0, -1, 0));
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(fixedJointObj == null )
        fixedJointObj = gameObject.AddComponent<FixedJoint>();

    Rigidbody body2;

    if ((body2 = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()) == null)
        return;

    fixedJointObj.connectedBody = body2;
}
```

Comment: If this answer has solved your problem feel free to close the question by marking as answer :)